# Neural Network for locating shifting resonant frequencies

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I have multiple FFT's taken from a sample at different pressures, through different analysis I can see that the resonant frequencies are shifting in the spectrum for each FFT at a different pressure.

Using conventional peak tracking has been difficult as the peaks increase/decrease in magnitude within the FFT as well as shifting in the spectrum.

Is it possible for a neural network to 'detect'/'pick out' these frequency values?

Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Try signalprocessing.se for your problem